# How to rate limit Google Cloud PubSub to align with quota limits on a different service using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-pubsub, rate-limiting

First off, thanks for taking the time to read my question. I'm sure you are busy with other things and want to say I greatly appreciate it. Now, the problem I want to solve (this is for work and I have no designers/architects to consult):

We are making HTTP requests to a service that has a QPM (quota per minute) in place of 25000 requests per minute. If we exceed this quota limit, we get an error from their service.

We are pulling messages to process from a queue (Google Cloud PubSub) using a Node.js event listener (listener.on("event", (data) { process... } ). This will pull messages as fast as the underlying hardware/processes allow it to. For practicality sake, let's say that messages can come in at an indefinite rate.

We currently set a cap of 25K maximum messages able to be pulled per minute. All messages after this will be ignored until the next minute interval. This number is to match the QPM. The problem I see here is that latency is not taken into account for each request made for each message.

We have exponential backoff in place using a factor of 1.4. This means any failed messages will be retried at a rate of 1000(x^1.4) milliseconds, where x is the attempt number. While this backoff can achieve reliability, the growing gap between retries means we have some waste while we are waiting if the service is ready for another request but we are still waiting to retry.

My question is: how can we achieve the highest possible throughput with our constraints? I'm just a mid-level dev but have been tasked with this issue and have no experience or mentorship to help me solve it. I would love any feedback, clarifying questions, etc. and would greatly appreciate really just any advice.

Thank you in advance!!